# QGIS 3.4.0 system freeze on MacOS 10.14

Tags: qgis, mac, qgis-browser

I've just installed the latest verion of QGIS (3.4.0) on a MacBook Pro 13" (3.3 GHz Core I7) MacOS 10.14. The application seemed to work fine at first.
On a certain point I've tried to open a recent project via Project/Open menu and had a system freeze for 12 seconds. During that time the whole system was not at all responsive (just mouse moves did work). None of the other applications worked in any way, I couldn't even move other app's windows, the system monitor didn't show any significant increase of activity and instead of the expected functional filemanager-window a tiny little inactive shadow of the filemanager-window was displayed ... as you might guess in the image below.

I was able to reproduce this behavior for several times - even after restart of QGIS.

The whole thing might be related to [QGIS 3.4.0 Madeira: unresponsive](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300626/qgis-3-4-0-madeira-unresponsive) but it is on a mac and it doesn't seem to affect the "rest" of QGIS.

... has anybody any idea how to handle that problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem oppening or saving files on QGIS 3.4.3 and Mojave 10.14. The bug was reported here [Bug report #20381](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20381) and looks to be related to MacOs acessibility stuff.

Thanks to **Yaroslav Vasyunin** a workaround was found. On your Mac, go to "System Preferences"-> "Security & Privacy" -> "Privacy" -> "Accessibility", and disable QGIS. It worked perfectly for me and will allow you to use it while a fix is on its way in next update.

Answer (score 1):

there is at least a working workaround: open qgis3 from terminal with the following command `open /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS`

see [bugreport](http://issues.qgis.org/issues/20381#change-95741)

Answer (score 0):

The first release of a new version always has bugs. Please make a bug report: https://issues.qgis.org.

Update: see the [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20381#change-95741) for the status of this bug.

---

Older versions of QGIS are available [here](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/) and [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive/qgis/), but not all versions are available for Mac.

See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/226634/81764) for more info about getting old versions of QGIS for Mac.

---

*Status report 2019_01_12*: the problem is still existing in version 3.4.3 ... which is the 4th version of 4. for more information see [here](http://www.issues.qgis.org/issues/20381#change-95741).

Answer (score 0):

thx to peter petrik and his post in 
[github osgeo issues/qgis3 homebrew fails](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/553) i have found a version that doesn't trigger a system freeze every time a file-related acitivity is started. packages provided by lutraconsulting here: [qgis 3.4.2 packages](https://lutraconsulting.github.io/qgis-mac-packager/) work without that kind of lags.

that package uses python 3.7 (!) which might cause troubles - thus my next step will be to find out how to switch from 3.6.x to 3.7. without affecting anything that is doing it's job right now.

Answer (score 0):

status at 2019 feb.: qgis issues report article at https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20381#change-95741 covers two different "**solutions**":

1. start qgis from terminal with `open /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS` or create a bash script (see bradypus' contribution bug report #48)
2. open "System Preferences"-> "Security & Privacy" -> "Privacy" -> "Accessibility", and disable QGIS

... see the ongoing discussion on the bug report page!